# Can not run UWP application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, uwp

I have a problem with launching a UWP application on Visual Studio:
[image: the error I get]

I have tried to Google the same issues, but none of the answers helped me. Output says:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
> The program '[17324] ReliveApp.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
> Activation of the Windows Store app 'b51cde60-b0a6-4f75-a6cd-82ca687fae96_psf1rkq97ps7e!App' failed with error 'Приложение не запустилось'.

Comment: Hello, you can try to uninstall the application in the start menu, then delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project, and rebuild the project. If the problem persists, please try to update Visual Studio to the latest version.

Comment: Select "Mixed (managed and native)" as the debugger type  for the application process in the project's properties.